# Problems with strptime

Tags: c, linux, time

I'm trying to parse date time like this,

```
char *line = "Feb 21 20:15:58";
struct tm t;

strptime (line, "%B %d %T", &t);
printf ("%ld\n", mktime (&t));
```

The output is `1`, am I using the wrong time format?

Comment: You have not specified the year.

Comment: @kaylum You're right, adding something like this `t.tm_year = 2017 - 1900;` works for me

Answer (score 0):

The `Year` is missing in your input variable `line`.

Also, from [Linux man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html),

> RETURN VALUE
>
> ```
>    The return value of the function is a pointer to the first character
>    not processed in this function call.  In case the input string
>    contains more characters than required by the format string, the
>    return value points right after the last consumed input character.
>    In case the whole input string is consumed, the return value points
>    to the null byte at the end of the string.  If strptime() fails to
>    match all of the format string and therefore an error occurred, the
>    function returns NULL.
> ```

And

> NOTES
>
> ```
>    In principle, this function does not initialize tm but stores only
>    the values specified.  This means that tm should be initialized
>    before the call.
> ```

So, apart from providing year to `strptime`, you should be checking the return value and you should initialize the `tm t` struct too before calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

**Reliance on uninitialized values**

`strptime()` does not set all members of `struct tm`.  Primarily, only the corresponding members of  `.tm_mon, .tm_mday, .tm_hour, .tm_min, .tm_sec` are affected by this format.  Best to first initialize all members.

```
// struct tm t;
struct tm t = {0};
strptime (line, "%B %d %T", &t);
```

**Year not set**

As identified by [@Abhineet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42359041/2410359), code should set the year.  Perhaps:

```
time_t now = time(0);
struct tm t = *localtime(&now);
strptime (line, "%B %d %T", &t);
```

**Matching print specifier**

`time_t` is some scalar, often an integer.  It is not specified to match `long`.  Recommend a cast to a wide integer type.

```
printf("%lld\n", (long long) mktime(&t));
```